# Whose sunshine do you belong to?

Tags: grammaticality, questions, who, whose

Are these sentences grammatically correct? They are translated from Thai song lyrics.

> Whose sunshine do you belong to? Who is your sunflower?

Comment: I see nothing ''grammatically'' wrong. The meanings however...

Comment: Same here. Grammar is fine, and even the semantics are okay. The overall gist, though, is definitely weird.

Comment: In Thai, it is written "you are the sunshine of who?".

Comment: In English it might make more sense to write, "Whose sunshine are you? Who is you sunflower?" It takes a little thought to work out what the lyrics are asking, but I kind of like them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the literal translation from Thai that you provided in comments, and on the normal interaction between sunshine and sunflowers, the sentence is grammatically correct but fails to convey the intention.

The word "of" in your literal translation doesn't mean you belong to that person's sunshine, but that you are the provider of the sunshine to the unnamed "who".

Try this as a translation: "Who are you shining on? Who is your sunflower?"

Answer (score 1):

The lyrics, though somewhat awkward sounding, are grammatically correct.

And while they are a little stilted, they are no more strange than the lyrics of the hits ["Steal My Sunshine"](https://youtu.be/E1fzJ_AYajA) or ["Walking on Sunshine,"](https://youtu.be/iPUmE-tne5U) or one of my all-time favorites, the Grammy-winning "Drops of Jupiter:"

```
But tell me, did you sail across the sun?
Did you make it to the Milky Way
To see the lights all faded
And that heaven is overrated?

Tell me, did you fall from a shooting star?
One without a permanent scar
And did you miss me
While you were looking for yourself out there?
```

Finally, to answer the "questions" the lyrics pose: my sunflower is my wife, and I belong to her sunshine. :-)

Good luck!